# SQL Vertica Timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, vertica

I have three values viz. a date value, an integer representing hour and an integer representing minute value.
I concatenated the three to form a timestamp like string:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( CAST(<DATE_VALUE> AS CHAR(10)) , 'T') , CAST(<hour_value> AS CHAR(2))) , ':' ) , CAST(<minutes_value> AS CHAR(2))) , ':' ) , '00' )
```

Now how do I convert the above created timestamp field another timezone (i.e to EST) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with code that you've attempted and where you're having difficulties

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `AT TIME ZONE 'EST'` but you will need to convert what you have to a timestamp first.

Also, you could just do something like: `(VIZ + HR/24 + MIN/24/60) AT TIME ZONE 'EST'` instead of all the string contortions.  Or you could use `INTERVAL` like: `( VIZ + (HR::INTERVAL HOUR) + (MIN::INTERVAL MINUTE) ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST'`

Example:

```
=> select ( VIZ + (HR::INTERVAL HOUR) + (MIN::INTERVAL MINUTE) ) AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS MY_TS
-> FROM (select trunc(now()) AS VIZ, 5 AS HR, 45 AS MIN) x;
        MY_TS
------------------------
 2015-09-03 05:45:00-05
(1 row)
```